# No converter found for 'java.lang.StackTraceElement'

Tags: java, spring, jboss, oracle11g, dwr

I am working on Spring3.0, Hibernate 3.2 web application deployed on JBOSS 4.3.
It's live product and getting this exception, when 30k users are utilizing it.

> **Exception** : level=ERROR class=org.directwebremoting.dwrp.DefaultConverterManager              No converter found for 'java.lang.StackTraceElement'

Its not generating much log as well and not able to find the same exception on internet.Anybody can tell me or any clue about it.
Why it's coming in production only not in local dev environment.

> How much impact can be done of this exception on the system ?

Comment: Hibernate Spring-MVC, JBoss and Oracle11g tags are not relevant to this question, while DWR tag is relevant to this question which is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the application generates exceptions under load and tries to send back stack traces from them to the client.  DWR is then unable to serialize the stack trace elements.

See [here](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/browser/errors.html) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/shedweb/source/browse/trunk/src/resources/spring/spring-dwr.xml?r=7) for possible DWR configurations that could solve the problem.